# Adding Sparse Matrices

Tags: c++, struct, sparse-matrix

For our programming class we have to add two sparse matrices together by reading 2 input files. We are required to use structs to store the values from the matrices, and dynamically allocate the size for the size of the element. I understand the logic behind allocating memory for the size of the matrix then reading through each line of the input matrix file to find the row (int r;), column (int c;), and that specific value (double value)> I understand that the values will only add if they are have the same location in the matrix. However, I am struggling how to approach this from a syntax standpoint. Here is what i have so far, and an example input file.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int size1 = 100;
int size2 = 100;


struct element
{
    int r;
    int c;
    double value;
};


int main()
{
    ifstream inputfile;
    inputfile.open("TextFile1.txt");
    string line;


    char ch;
    int i = 0;
    int r; 
    int c;
    double value;

    for (i = 0; i <= 0; i++)
    {
        getline(inputfile, line);
        inputfile >> r >> c;

    }
    size1 = (r + 1) * (c + 1);

    while (getline(inputfile, line))
    {
        inputfile >> r >> c >> value;
        cout << r << c << value << endl;
    }
    element m1[10];
    {
        m1[0].r = r;
        m1[1].c = c;
        m1[2].value = value;
    }
    cout << m1[0].r << m1[1].c << m1[2].value << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Input File:

```
#Matrix A
2 2
1 1 2.2
2 2 3
```

So far this only stores the int r, int c, and double value for the last line of the matrix, and I'm confused why its skipping over the first line(1 1 2.2)? I also am having difficulty figuring out how to create a separate struct for each line in the matrix file. Without doing the work for me, could anyone give a few tips on how I should go about storing the information from the input file and how that'll translate to having to find values in the same place to add?

Update: I am still having issues because of my for loop. What I was trying to do was skip the line that contained a '#' but the code won't work if say that '#' is anywhere else in the code. (For the example input given to us there are some with '#' randomly embedded in the code and we must find a way to skip that line if there is one)

Answer (score 0):

```
while (getline(inputfile, line))
{
    inputfile >> r >> c >> value;
    cout << r << c << value << endl;
}
```

This will read each line from the file...and then do nothing with it. At the end of the loop, those variables are left with the values from the last line they read.

You then take what's left in those variables and stick it into your element array.

You need to be updating the element array *as* you're looping through, as opposed to after. The program won't remember your variables unless you put them somehwere!

You probably want something like:

```
int line = 0;
element m1[10];
while (inputfile >> r >> c >> value)
{
    cout << r << c << value << endl;
    m1[line].r = r;
    m1[line].c = c;
    m1[line].value = value;
    line++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused why its skipping over the first line(1 1 2.2)?
This code don't skip over the first line(1 1 2.2).
In my understanding, the first line 2 2, tells us the dimension of sparse matrix(3*3). The next part is the element value in sparse matrix(row, col, value).
I recommend you use vector(vector< element >) to solve this problem.

```
vector<element> m1;
while (getline(inputfile, line))
{
    inputfile >> r >> c >> value;
    cout << r << c << value << endl;
    element tmp = {r,c,value};
    m1.push_back(tmp);
    line++;
}
```